# What are the security features of the proposed "secure email" from Brazil?

Tags: email, international, nsa

[Brazil has announced](http://www.bnamericas.com/news/technology/brazil-to-create-national-encrypted-email-to-dodge-espionage) that they will create a secure email alternative in light of NSA spy programs. The company [Correios](http://www.correios.com.br/) will be implementing the contract over the next year or so.

What are the security features that will be included in this email platform?

Comment: The answer will be "no one knows at this very moment."

Comment: This will be for Meta; but are asking preemtive questions that will be answered in the future off topic?  Several questions fit this model such as the CRIME attack on TLS  security.stackexchange.com/q/19911/396

Comment: Definitely worth a post on meta. My opinion is that speculative questions will not add much to the site and should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

*No one knows at this very moment.* (thanks @Terry)

It is highly possible that it is not even *defined*. There are several options, depending on what the Brazil government wants to do: do they want to stop spying, or do they want to stop spying *from NSA* ? (In the latter case, this means that Brazil could want to maintain possibility of spying *by themselves*).

The linked article contains the following excerpt:

> Data will be stored on local servers.

and also that one:

> For the user of the future service to actually be protected, however, the message recipient will also have to use Correios' email.

Both hint at some sort of network of decentralized encryption gateways. End users would connect to a specific gateway which would do all encryption and decryption, and ensure protection against spies *on the big network links*. However, the gateways would be in ideal place to spy on users. In a business context, we may imagine that each corporation would run its own gateway.

NSA spies would have to fall back to the methods that they.. already use... e.g. keyloggers or even simple bribery. Let it be a message: ye shall pay your sysadmins well, because they *can* see everything if they are such inclined.